# How did Luthor's wheelchair bomb get past security?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, batman-v-superman-dawn-of-justice, lex-luthor

In the movie *Batman v Superman: Dawn of Justice*, Lex Luthor successfully bombs the Capitol building. It was a powerful bomb; everyone except Superman died in the blast.

But, how did such a powerful bomb get past the security?

**Note:** Luthor gained access to the Kryptonian knowledge archive *after* the bombing. So, that bomb was definitely not alien to evade detection.

Comment: He has lots of money. All the money in fact.

Comment: He hid it. Really well.

Comment: There is stringent security around the President.  Americans ***really*** don't mind if members of Congress get blown to pieces. https://www.realclearpolitics.com/epolls/latestpolls/

Answer (score 22):

### The wheelchair was lead-lined.

The wheelchair was lead-lined to hide the bomb. I'm not sure that this was clarified in the theatrical cut but I'm pretty sure it was explicit in the DVD/Blu-Ray releases. No need to lead line a wheelchair unless you're hiding it from x-ray vision.

> ...Later in the film, she [Jena Malone, playing a forensic scientist] calls Lois to say she did an analysis of the materials in **Wally’s explosive wheelchair** and found that it contained …… **lead!** After Superman appears before a congressional subcommittee to talk about the Nairomi incident and Wally’s IED-chair kills every human inside, Supes wonders why he didn’t see the bomb. **Now we know it’s because the vehicle was lined with lead**, which the Man of Steel traditionally can’t see through.
>
> <sup>[Vulture.com re Ultimate Edition Release](http://www.vulture.com/2016/06/batman-superman-ultimate-edition-additions.html)</sup>

How the explosive evaded **human** detectors etc (plus wouldn't a lead-lined wheelchair be somewhat suspicious when x-rayed?) is not clear but it's possible the explosive was a new LuthorCorp invention not detectable using the technology available to Capitol security.

Comment: Also don't think too hard about why Supes didn't hear the wheelchair ticking.

Comment: @GGMC - a digital, electronic timer (assuming it wasn't just remotely detonated by Luthor) has to "tick?"  That's very 1940s.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet Everybody knows that digital electronic timers beep, not tick! (I was once hugely amused that a movie bomb used the same electronic timer my that my mother uses in the kitchen. Obviously, it doesn't beep every second, because that would drive you insane. Obviously, the movie timer did beep every second.)

Answer (score 10):

The answer is he hid it inside a wounded veteran's wheelchair. The man, confined to a wheelchair, was likely not viewed as a threat and likely not subjected to additional security screening. Relevant portion happens at 2:31, where you see the explosion originate at the man